# How I can use unity render 3D model and native android?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I try to develop an app on **AR**, so the command way for developing app on **AR** is:

1. **Unity** and **Vuforia**.
2. Native **android** app and **Vuforia**.

The first way: I lose android App UI.

The second way: I lose unity render special in a complex model.

I fond another way to use android UI and unity render model by the export jar from unity app to the android studio but this way is slow and I need to export unity project in each time my list change.
I try **WebGL** but **WebGL** is not worked with Vuforia, and I can't find enough info about it. 
How I can use unity render 3d model and native android without export data in each time data changed from unity to the android studio.

Comment: what part of androind native UI want to use? You mentioned "I lose android app UI" what do you mean by that? You will need to elaborate on that.

Comment: in my App, I use a list and this list gets images and data products from the server each time user change data or adds a product, so doing that in unity take a lot of time and not safe.

Comment: The Wikitude SDK might be an alternative for you. You can implement natively for iOS and Android, or consider to implement the AR part in JS. Wikitude comes with its own render engine. A downside is that you cannot use physics or particles like in Unity. And the Wikitude license is more expensive than Vuforia's. 
Vuforia's tracking performance is slightly better than Wikitude's, but if you have a very good tracking pattern, it is almost the same. 
https://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/latest/androidnative/
Another AR SDK is by https://www.kudan.eu/

Comment: Thanks for Help, If I want to avoid use Wikitude SDK because it is expensive to start a project, can I use  https://github.com/jeromeetienne/AR.js/, so when user click show AR button I can open the browser to show him the AR model.